# Troubleshooting NoSuchElementException in Selenium when finding elements by XPATH

Tags: element

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element:

Hello I am trying to run the code from freecodecamp in re: automating news; and I have tried the solutions but I constantly get errors (above). Any idea how I can solve this error?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import pandas as pd

website = "https://www.glassmagazine.com/news"
#path of chrome driver
path = "CHROMEDRIVE LOC"


service = Service(executable_path=path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get(website)



containers = driver.find_elements(by="xpath", value='//h2[@class="title-item-teaser"]/a') and driver.find_elements(by="xpath", value='//div[@class="summary-content"]/p')


titles = []
highlights = []
links = []


for container in containers:
    title = container.find_element(by="xpath", value='//h2[@class="title-item-teaser"]/a').text
    highlight = container.find_element(by="xpath", value='//div[@class="summary-content"]/p').text
    link = container.find_element(by="xpath", value='h2[@class="title-item-teaser"]/a').get_attribute("href")
    titles.append(title)
    highlights.append(highlight)
    links.append(link)

my_dict = {'titles': titles, 'highlights': highlights, 'links': links}

df_headlines = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df_headlines.to_csv('headlines.csv')

driver.quit()
```